# Tribute js - replace matched text that contains spaces

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I'm using tribute js (https://github.com/zurb/tribute) for autocomplete funcionality on textarea element. It works fine for words without spaces, but if word contains space only last part of word is replaced by selected list item.

Example: if you type "java scr" and matched item is "java script" you'll get "java java script" after item selection.

Is there a way to replace whole matched text?

```
var tributeAttributes = {
    autocompleteMode: true,
    replaceTextSuffix: "",
    allowSpaces: true,
    requireLeadingSpace: false,
    noMatchTemplate: "",
    values: [
      { key: "ASP", value: "ASP" },
      { key: "C#", value: "C#" },
      { key: "Java script", value: "Java script" },
      { key: "PHP", value: "PHP" }
   ],
    selectTemplate: function(item) {
      if (typeof item === "undefined") return null;
      if (this.range.isContentEditable(this.current.element)) {
        return (
          '<span contenteditable="false"><a>' +
          item.original.key +
          "</a></span>"
        );
      }
      return item.original.value;
    },
    menuItemTemplate: function(item) {
      return item.string;
    }
};

var tributeTextarea = new Tribute(
    Object.assign(
      {
        menuContainer: document.getElementById("textarea_container")
      },
      tributeAttributes
    )
  );

  tributeTextarea.attach(
    document.getElementById("textarea")
  );
```